# Merge two Object based on Object one value with Object two key

Tags: javascript, object

Want to merge object key values with another object value.

Suppose results object key should match with headers object key_name match because header should be CamelCase.
I have headers object is:

```
let headers = [
  { key_name: 'pid', header_value: 'PID' },
  {
    key_name: 'card_no',
    header_value: 'Card Number'
  },
  {

    key_name: 'trans_id',
    header_value: 'Transaction ID'
  },
  {
    key_name: 'card_name',
    header_value: 'Card Name'
  }
]
```

results Object is:

```
let results = let results = [
  {
    pid: '1234567890',
    card_no: '546.......3742',
    trans_id: '2019124453159',
    card_name: 'Mastercard',
    code: '$'
  },
  {
    pid: '1234567890',
    card_no: '546.......3742',
    trans_id: '2019120534555',
    card_name: 'Visa',
    code: 'INR'
  }
]
```

Header object key_name matching values need to filter in final results Object like below.
expected results is:

```
let results = [
  {
    PID: '1234567890',
    Card Number: '546.......3742',
    Transaction ID: '2019124453159',
    Card Name: 'Mastercard'
  },
  {
    PID: '1234567890',
    Card Number: '546.......3742',
    Transaction ID: '2019120534555',
    Card Name: 'Visa'
  }
]
```

I tried with below script its returning all values only:

```
for (let index = 0; index < results.length; index++) {
for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {

console.log(results [index][header[i].key_name])
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Nitheesh I updated my snippet

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest turning the first object into a map, so you have faster look-up. Then turn your objects into key/value pairs with `Object.entries`, perform the mapping and the filtering, and then turn those pairs back to an object with `Object.fromEntries`

```js
let headers = [{ key_name: 'pid', header_value: 'PID' },{key_name: 'card_no',header_value: 'Card Number'},{key_name: 'trans_id',header_value: 'Transaction ID'},{key_name: 'card_name',header_value: 'Card Name'}];

// Convert to map:
let map = new Map(headers.map(({key_name, header_value}) => [key_name, header_value]));

let arr = [{pid: '1234567890',card_no: '546.......3742',trans_id: '2019124453159',card_name: 'Mastercard',code: '$'},{pid: '1234567890', card_no: '546.......3742',trans_id: '2019120534555',card_name: 'Visa',code: 'INR'}];

// Use map to make transition
let result = arr.map(obj => 
    Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => 
        map.has(key) && [map.get(key), value]
    ).filter(Boolean))
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look into the `Object.keys(..)` of the results array so you can map the old key values to the new ones.
You could use something like this:

```js
  const mappedHeaders = results.map((r) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(r);
    let newObj = {};
    for (const key of keys) {
      const newHeader = headers.find((h) => h.key_name === key);
      if (newHeader) newObj[newHeader.header_value] = r[key];
    }
    return newObj;
  });
```

You may need to check if the mapping exists and handle such cases to avoid errors.